# Want to change field in yii from

Tags: jquery, yii

What I want to know is that, I want to change textField or dropDownList on dropDownlist change using jQuery.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'name',array('prompt'=>'Select')); ?>
                                OR
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
```

I have another dropdownlist,

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'type', array('car'=>'Car', 'train'=>'Train', 'cruise'=>'Cruise', 'airline'=>'Airline'), array('prompt'=>'Select Type')); ?>
```

According to **type** dropdownlist's change function I only want to show **name** textfield or **name** dropdownlist, their field are same but I don't know to do that. My jquery is like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Transport_type').change(function() {
        var trantype = $('#Transport_type').val();       
        if(trantype == 'car' || trantype == 'train'){
          //Here I wanna show dropdownlist             
        }else if(trantype == 'cruise' || trantype == 'airline'){
          //Here I wanna show textfield
        }
      });
   });
```

It'll be great if someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'name',array('prompt'=>'Select'),array('style'=>'display:none;')); ?>
                                OR
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100,style'=>'display:none;')); ?>
```

When i Change this

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'type', array('car'=>'Car', 'train'=>'Train', 'cruise'=>'Cruise', 'airline'=>'Airline'), array('prompt'=>'Select Type')); ?>
```

Then what you ve written is correct and will work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Transport_type').change(function() {
        var trantype = $(this).val();       
        if(trantype == 'car' || trantype == 'train'){
          $('#dropdownid').show(); 
        }else if(trantype == 'cruise' || trantype == 'airline'){
          $('#textboxid').show();
        }
      });
   });
```

Comment: But their ids are same because they are same field. But I wanna show as dropdownlist or textfield on type dropdownlist's change.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar, with a very small change in order to hide the dropdown which should not be shown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Transport_type').change(function() {
        var trantype = $(this).val();       
        if(trantype == 'car' || trantype == 'train'){
          $('#dropdownid').show(); 
          $('#textboxid').hide();  
        }else if(trantype == 'cruise' || trantype == 'airline'){
          $('#textboxid').show();
          $('#dropdownid').hide()
        }
      });
   });
```

If using models, you can also replace the IDs for the automatically generated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#<?php echo CHtml::activeId($model, "type"); ?>").change(function() {
        var trantype = $(this).val();       
        if(trantype == 'car' || trantype == 'train'){
          $('#dropdownid').show(); 
          $('#textboxid').hide();  
        }else if(trantype == 'cruise' || trantype == 'airline'){
          $('#textboxid').show();
          $('#dropdownid').hide()
        }
      });
   });
```

By doing so, you're protecting your code for changes on the framework that would change how form Ids are automatically generated.

If Ids are the same, you should use JQuery append and destroy and destroy/create en element on the change of the type in order to solve this issue.

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to POST data if you don't disable the inactive Yii form field.

You can do this easily by adding one thing using jQuery. That is, use **"DISABLED"** property for the yii form field which is inactive. This will not consider that one, then. Also, at first, when form loads, disable that form field which will be shown on Type change dropdown.

and ALso, u have to remove the **"REQUIRED"** from the name field in the model and can be made required using javascript/jquery prior to validation of the Yii form.

HTML:

```
<div id="dropdownId">
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'name',array('prompt'=>'Select')); ?>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" id="textboxId">
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100,'disabled'=>'disabled')); ?>
</div> 

<?php echo $form->error($model, 'name'); ?>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#Transport_type').change(function() {
    var trantype = $('#Transport_type').val();       
    if(trantype == 'car' || trantype == 'train'){
      //Here I wanna show dropdownlist       
      $("#dropdownId").show();
      $("#textboxId").hide();
      $("#textboxId input").prop("disabled",true);
      $("#dropdownId select").prop("disabled",false);
    }else if(trantype == 'cruise' || trantype == 'airline'){
      //Here I wanna show textfield
      $("#textboxId").show();
      $("#dropdownId").hide();
      $("#dropdownId select").prop("disabled",true);
      $("#textboxId input").prop("disabled",false);
    }
  });
```

I hope, it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Transport_type').change(function() {
        var trantype = $('#Transport_type').val();       
        if(trantype == 'car' || trantype == 'train'){
           $('input#Transport_name').show();          
           $('select#Transport_name').hide();          
        }else if(trantype == 'cruise' || trantype == 'airline'){
            $('input#Transport_name').hide();          
           $('select#Transport_name').show();  
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Try this one.